# How can I do G-d's will if I don't believe in divine command theory?

Tags: catholicism, will-of-god, divine-law

St. Alphonsus de Liguori in his tract *Uniformity With G-d's Will* writes that the greatest thing in the universe is doing G-d's will. But that presupposes divine command theory: the notion that G-d first wills something, and then it becomes good because He willed it. So G-d, in an alternative universe, could have willed "thou shalt commit adultery" and it would have been good, but He didn't, so adultery just happens to be bad in this universe and you're uniting yourself to G-d's will by opposing adultery (but it could have just as easily been otherwise).

How do non-believers in divine command theories of morality find happiness in doing G-d's will?

Comment: "But that presupposes divine command theory" No it doesn't.

Comment: @eques Yes it does? Why would you want to do G-d's will unless you believed that anything G-d wills automatically becomes good?

Comment: No. At best, doing God's will implies it is good, but it's either a) already good or b) good because it is willed.

Comment: What I said is b)

Comment: And note it only implies that it is Good entirely if you accept that God does not will evil, which incidentally is a premise of Catholic theology (and Aristotle's natural theology).

Comment: I'm aware you said b. My point is that b isn't the only option, hence your question doesn't follow from St. Alphonsus' statement.

Comment: I ignored a) because a) implies that even an atheist can do G-d's will in a cooperative fashion, as opposed to an uncooperative fashion like Caiaphas or Pharaoh. So b) is the only logical option for a right-thinking Catholic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140703/discussion-between-eques-and-amatsukilove).

Comment: Aren't questions like this more suitable for [Philosophy Stack Exchange](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: @amatsuki could you please make it very clear if you're looking for Catholic answers.  The class of "non-believers in divine command theories of morality seeking happiness" is nebulous at best and we need some perspective to match answers to.

Comment: @PeterTurner I'm sorry, but this is the clearest I can express my thoughts.

Comment: That's fine, if you're satisfied with the answer you've chosen, we'll just leave the question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simplicity in God such that all His attributes work together harmoniously. By creating us in His image, there is in us a corresponding integrity (to the extent that such integrity has not been violated by sin).

Thus God's nature, words, actions, commands and all the rest are in harmony. Goodness in essence, nature, commands and such are all connected. Most theories of causality break down when speaking of the Godhead because God created time. There is no before and after in His "history" so no action can cause a subsequent action in the way we normally think of causation. A static causation is more like a blueprint showing how the pieces are assembled.

So God has created us with a conscience. An intact, properly functioning conscience or one restored by the Holy Spirit delights in doing what is good. God's commands are written on our hearts. Thus the conscience produces joy when we follow God's will or guilt when we oppose that will. Human Conscience and God's will are prepared in parallel to work together, as well as every other part of the moral and volitional apparatus that He has built into us.

Comment: The question is tagged with Catholicism, which is also backed up by remarks by OP in the comments, yet this doesn't seem to align with Catholic theology

Comment: At the time I answered there was also a Protestantism tag, which seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 1):

Not only does this seem backwards, but its very backwardness suggests the answer.

I don't believe that something *becomes* Good because God wills it. I believe that God's nature is such that what He wills is Good. Now, one has to be careful here with cause and effect as there is a clear possibility of heresy, but at risk of oversimplifying, I would assert that the proper relation is closer to one of intertwined cause. More practically, we *learn* that something is Good through knowing that God wills that thing.

More to the question... there is no such thing as a universe where God wills something that is not Good, because that would violate God's nature. (Keep in mind that we're in "can God make a rock so large He can't lift it" territory. "Omnipotence" doesn't mean God can violate fundamental truths, but this is not a limitation on omnipotence.) One might argue whether these unalterable truths themselves result from God's nature, but the point is that they do not arise from any *volitional* cause. They simply *are*.

IIUC, that makes me a "non-believers in divine command theories", and therefore qualified to answer?

It should also, however, make the answer obvious. Doing God's Will is beneficial because that Will is Good... but, while being united with God's Will may (and I would argue, does) have its own benefits, doing Good is inherently beneficial.

To give a more specific example, could God will that people commit adultery? Perhaps, although such a universe would necessarily be one in which adultery *is* Good, and thus would probably be quite different from our own.